# Mentioning user name in a comment doesn't work

Tags: support

I am trying to mention user nik90 in a comment, so I start with @nik90. After saving the comment, the whole string "@nik90" is deleted. Editing doesn't bring it back. What do I do wrong?

Comment: See e.g. [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/445885/why-do-i-see-two-network-indicators-in-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: He is the only other commenter and the owner of the post. You don't need to @ ping him so the system won't let you.

Comment: @Seth thanks, that makes sense.